# How to position images at the same spot all android devices?

Tags: android

I have to position the images on my layout such that it does not change its position with varying screen resolutions. They should be exactly where they are placed. layout_weight attribute can be used with linear layout. But I am using relative layout and I am dealing with cropped images. Any solution on how to position the image views? Setting out margin height and width is not worth.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve more clearly? Do you want the images at an exact pixel location?

Comment: Image Views that I am using are the different parts of an animated character. So, even a minor difference of position between two images has to be avoided.

Comment: Each frame is an ImageView? That's pretty wasteful, take a look at AnimationDrawable. Also, if the frames are the same pixel sizes, as long you use the same scaleType on all ImageViews, the character will be the same size between frames.

Comment: Position your first image where you want it on the screen, and then use it as an anchor for the other parts of the animated character. That is, use the RelativeLayout verbs such as `toRightOf` or `below` to position the other images relative to the first, with margin set to 0.

Comment: I am talking about different body parts. Imagine you are given images of hand,head of a robot and you have to fix them at their respective positions. and it shud look perfect on all android devices..then how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

In short - you can't. Devices have different resolutions as well as screen sizes ratio. Thus it's impossible for the app to look `same` because there is no `same` definition in Android. The only way to design an interface - is to use bindings to other objects or parent view's borders. Try to investigate what are the rules, e.g. "to the bottom of the picture with 10dp gap" or "next to the TextView" - and it's the constants that are kept on every device.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a scenario where this makes sense but it obviously must exist since the Android team built support for it. The docs on the [dimension type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) clearly state that it supports "mm" and "in" as qualifiers for millimetres and inches respectively.

That should get you what you need but I would advise reevaluating that requirement, as it would make design a massive pain.